# Session Management with Sharp UMS

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am very new to the MVC style of programming. I have a management script that I would like to be able to integrate the user credentials into my browser application. User information such as username, email, name, etc. The [**documentation**](http://demos.denonstudio.net/sharpums/docs/) for this system provides a clear explanation for generating this information. I have done so in the following script which works fine, but it will always return "AUTH_NO_SESSION" because I have no way of allowing the user to log in to get this information and that is my issue:

**User Information (user_cred.php)**

```
include_once("includes.php"); 
$auth = new TAuthentication();    
$accept_roles = array('plugin');
$auth_result  = $auth->validateSession($accept_roles);

if ($auth_result->auth_code == AUTH_NO_SESSION) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    echo "AUTH_NO_SESSION";
    // means that no session was found, therefore the page is being accessed anonymously.
} elseif ($auth_result->auth_code == AUTH_OKAY) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    echo "AUTH_OKAY";
    // means that there was a session and the user owns all the required roles to access this content.
} elseif ($auth_result->auth_code == AUTH_INSUFFICIENT_ROLES) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    echo "AUTH_INSUFFICIENT_ROLES";
    // means that a session exists, but the user does not own the required roles to access this content.
} else {
    // no code here
}
```

The browser application will retrieve the user data from `user_cred.php` file listen above. 
Everything works fine as far as requesting information from this php file. The problem I am faced with is actually getting the users information, and the only way to do that is for the user to log into their account. Other wise nothing will be given.

**Browser Application**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","user_cred.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest object</h2>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

In the management system there is a `view` file that has the following login form. So that users and access the website. You also have the main index file that has the login code. With my limited knowledge I have looked at this and believe these two files will help me with my script so that the users can log in from the browser application and get their user credentials. My thought would be to add the code from the the index.php file into the user_cred.php file so that i can add a url like this `http://website.com/user_cred.php?username=admin&pass=test&signin=Login` in to the javascript httprequest and get the user info that way

**login view**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li class="listitem">
            <div class="row">
                <label>Username:</label>
                <input class="textbox" type="text" name="username" value="" maxlength="80"/>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input class="textbox" type="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="80"/>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="listitem">
            <div class="row">
                <input class="form-button" type="submit" name="signin" value="Signin"/>
                <a class="loginoptions indentmore" href="signup.php">Signup</a>
                <a class="loginoptions" href="resetpassword.php">Forgot your password?</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

**index.php**

```
include_once("includes.php");

class TSigninController extends TAbstractController {

    public function run($allowedRoles = null)
    {
        $this->allowedRoles = $allowedRoles;
        $this->execute();
    }

    protected function execute() 
    {
        $this->auth_result = parent::validateSession(null);

        if ($this->auth_result->auth_code == AUTH_OKAY)
        {
            $this->goToAfterSignInPage($this->auth_result->roles);
        }
        else if (!$this->getUserAction())
        {
            $this->loadview("signin");
        }
        else
        {
            $this->signin();        
        }
    }

    protected function signin()
    {
        $input   = $this->getUserInput();
        $model   = $this->loadmodel("Users");
        $account = $model->getUser($input["username"], $input["password"]);

        if ($account == null || sizeof($account) == 0) 
        {
            $data = array("error" => "Could not sign you in");
            $this->loadview("signin", $data);
            return;
        } 

        if ($account["disabled"] == 1 || $account["admin_disabled"] == 1) 
        {
            $data = array("error" => ($account["admin_disabled"] == 0) ? "This account is disabled." : "This account is been locked by the admin. Please contact the site admin!");
            $this->loadview("signin", $data);
            return;
        } 

        $this->createNewSession($account);
        $this->goToAfterSignInPage($account["roles"]);
    }

    protected function createNewSession($account) {
        $model     = $this->loadmodel("Sessions");
        $sessionid = crypt($account["username"] . date('now'));

        $_SESSION['SESSIONID'] = $sessionid;
        $model->createNewSession($sessionid, $account["id"]);
    }

    public function goToAfterSignInPage($roles)
    {
        foreach($roles as $role)
        {
            if ($this->utils->stringsEqual($role["name"], "admin", false))
            {
                $this->redirect(SITE_URL . "/admin/dashboard.php");
                return;
            }
        }

        $this->redirect(SITE_URL . "/user/userprofile.php");
    }

    protected function getUserAction()
    {
        if ($this->post("signin"))
            return "signin";
        else     
            return null;            
    }

    protected function getUserInput()
    {
        return array(
            "username" => $this->post("username"),
            "password" => $this->post("password")
        );
    }
}

$controller = new TSigninController();
$controller->run();
```

In conclusion I am seeking help so that I cam make a php script `user_cred.php` that allows  users to access their credentials from within my browser application. So anyone with MVC and PHP knowledge I would be very greatful.

Comment: First off way to much information here. You need to be more specific to the question giving us only the information we need. Second, is this actually a MVC or is it a FrontEndControlloer-MVC mixture? From the documentation it looks like most of the session tracking is in the controller layer. Is that what you need to know, if not a more specific question would be helpful?

Comment: @ars265 Unfortunately I don't know much about MVC so I couldn't tell you one form the other, but if I could sum it all up. I just want to make it so what when a button is clicked the information from `user_cred.php` is displayed to the user. Accessing `user_cred.php` directly will not give any user information. I even tried `http://website.com/user_cred.php?username=admin&pass=test&signin=Login` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The description of MVC, provided by SharpUMS, was quite dreadful. And the effort required to get the source of SharpUMS makes me think that it is not an opensource project .. oh well.

There can be two reasons why `$auth_result->auth_code === AUTH_NO_SESSION` is `true`:

- `$_SESSION['SESSIONID']` is empty
- the session ID was no found in database:

  > <sub>**from:** *sharpums/_application/models/Session.php*</sub>

  ```
  SELECT 
      s.userid, 
      s.id, 
      s.started_on, 
      ( 
          DATE_ADD(
               s.started_on, 
               INTERVAL $this->sessionlength SECOND
          ) < NOW()
      ) expired 
  FROM sessions s 
  WHERE s.id = '$sessionid'
  ```

Basically, bot reasons track back to *index.php*. I would guess, that this method is never executed:

```
protected function createNewSession($account) {
    $model     = $this->loadmodel("Sessions");
    $sessionid = crypt($account["username"] . date('now'));

    $_SESSION['SESSIONID'] = $sessionid;
    $model->createNewSession($sessionid, $account["id"]);
}
```

You should try to find out, at which point the `signin()` method gets terminated.

### Side notes

Free advice: **do not use SharpUMS** as the basis for you application or research in MVC as whole because of following reasons:

- to ensure single DB connection `TDatabase` uses global state to hold the connection
- it is tightly bound to the ancient `mysql_*` API, which is in process of deprecation
- the `TAbstractModel` is not really abstract, and it creates new DB instance in constructor
- design issues: core classes depends on models (which are outside core)
- `TUtilities` class is a huge dumping ground (see [2.1 Adopter](http://www.lsd.ic.unicamp.br/~oliva/fun/prog/resign-patterns) pattern)
- passwords are stored as simple MD5 hashes ..heard about LinkedIn incident?
- **weak protection against SQL injections**: utilizes `preg_*` and `addslashes()` functions

Comment: Second the not using SharpUMS. there are several great ones out there though such as CodeIgniter.

Comment: @ars265 , if you read the source of CI, you will notice that it is filled with flaws, such as use of global state, tight coupling, leaky abstractions and very *loose* definition of what MVC is (CI pretends that view is a template and model is an ORM).

Comment: You're right as far as what you've stated above. I was actually meaning it's a great platform to start learning with. I know Code-Igniter is actually a Front-End Controller architecture tied with MVC and others and has issues, as all do, but it still represents a great learning environment.

Comment: @ars265: learning =/= misguided. You should not suggest CI as a learning experience in 2012.